# Posting input form array in another php page

Tags: php

I have this piece of code which permits me to print multiple dates, so this is the form, which gets populated with dates separated by a comma, like 19/02/1990,12/12/1220 etc etc..

Now, what i need to do is to save them in an array and then print the array!

For the moment i have this code, could you please help me?
Thanks!

```
<form action="insert_date.php" method="post">    
<div id="with-altField"></div>
<input type="text" id="altField" name="altField">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This doesn't work if i select more than one date, but if i select one, it does, that's why i need to save it in an array form!

insert_date.php

```
<?php
$date=$_POST['altField'];
echo $date;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dates = explode(",", $_POST['altField']);
foreach($dates as $date){
    echo htmlentities($date, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked :)
I'll have to wait a few minutes until i can accept this answer!

Comment: Just be careful. This isn't exactly foolproof. You should try and validate each date before you print to screen because if somebody types "19/02/2012,blah,29/02/2012", "blah" will be printed out.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<?php
    $dates      =  $_POST['altField'];
    $arrOfDates = explode(',', $dates);
    var_dump($arrOfDates);
    foreach($arrOfDates as $date)
    {
       echo $date;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're va_dumping a var that doesn't exist. Should be var_dump($arrOfDates).

Answer (score 0):

On `insert_date.php` you can explode by `,`

```
<?php
    $date=$_POST['altField'];
    $explode = explode(',', $date);
?>
```

then you can use `foreach` to parse your dates

```
<?php
    foreach($explode as $date){
        echo trim($date);
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you have a space after the comma remember to `trim()` the resulting date strings.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply :)
Could you please show me how to print the array inside the foreach?